# Can someone help me with this python problem?

Tags: python, input

im new at coding (i started today) and i am trying to do a (If you are older than 18, you can enter this website) but when you put you are over 18, it says you cannot enter (because it only lets you enter when you put the same word at 'Age' than at 'Name'

Example.1 Program says: Enter your name:

User enters name: John

Program responds: Hi John, How old are you?

User enters age: 23

Response: You cannot enter to this website

Only lets you in if:

Ex.2 Program says: Enter your name:

User enters name: John

Program responds: Hi John, How old are you?

User enters age: John

Response: You can enter this website

Can you see the problem i refeer? i need help because i dont know whats going on jejeje

```
  overage = '18'

name = input('Enter your name: ')

print("Hi " + name)
                               
age = input('How old are you?:')

if age >= 'overage':
    print('You can enter this website.')
else:
    print('You cannot enter to this website')
```

Comment: `overage = '18'` is setting 18 to be a string not an integer (int in Python). And the line ```if age >= 'overage':``` is not looking at the variable `overage` but looking the string 'overage'  Take a look at this article about strings and integers in python: https://careerkarma.com/blog/python-string-to-int/

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Thank you for helping, it is my first question here and i didnt know how to say it properly, next time i will try to put a better title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the lesson here is twofold:

- When you take in an input from a user; it's a string and you must
  convert it to an int
- '18' is a string for 18, and that is not the same as 18 on it's own and must be evaluated differently

  overage = 18

  ```
   name = input('Enter your name: ')

   print("Hi " + name)

   age = input('How old are you?:')

   if int(age) >= overage:
       print('You can enter this website.')
   else:
       print('You cannot enter to this website')
  ```

Comment: Thank you for helping

Answer (score 1):

1. The value of `overage` should be an integer, not a string.
2. You need to convert the user's input to an integer using `int()`
3. You need to take the quotes off `overage` when comparing, so that it will use the value of the variable, not the literal string.

```
overage = 18

name = input('Enter your name: ')

print("Hi " + name)
                               
age = int(input('How old are you?:'))

if age >= overage:
    print('You can enter this website.')
else:
    print('You cannot enter to this website')
```

Answer (score 1):

your overage is a string meaning it's not a number so that's one problem change it to : `overage = 18`
second thing, when you are checking `if age >= 'overage'` change it to `if int(age) >= overage:`

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping. I already tried that, but it shows me this: line 10, in <module>
    if age >= overage:
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: becuase you have to convert age into an int like so : int(age)

Comment: Thank you for helping

Comment: you are very welcome Pablo. Good luck with coding and don't forget to have fun with it!

Answer (score 1):

So your problem is that you had `overage` store the number 18 as a string not an integer. An integer doesn't include quotation marks. The line `if age >= 'overage':` is wrong as well. `overage` is a variable not a string so you shouldn't have quotation marks on that as well.

This is what the final code should look like:

```
overage = 18

name = input('Enter your name: ')

print(f'Hi {name}')

age = int(input('How old are you? '))

if age >= overage:
    print('You can enter this website.')
else:
    print('You cannot enter to this website')
```

I also changed `print("Hi " + name)` to a formatted string as it generally looks cleaner.

Comment: Thank you for helping

Answer (score 1):

Edited your code, please see comments in code for the explanation of what was changed and why

```
# overage should be an integer, so take it out of quotes
overage = 18

name = input('Enter your name: ')

print("Hi " + name)

# loop until you get an integer for age, at which time break out of the loop
while True:

    # try-except block to ensure if a string that can't be converted to int is input, 
    # the user is notified and asked to enter an integer
    try: 

        # age must be an integer, so convert your input to int                            
        age = int(input('How old are you?:'))
        break

    # user input non-integer, request an integer for age
    except:
        print('Please enter an integer for age.')

# overage should be an integer, so take it out of quotes here, too
if age >= overage:
    print('You can enter this website.')
else:
    print('You cannot enter to this website')
```

Answer (score 1):

You are checking if `age >= 'overage'`, this won't work as you want to know if it is the same. You would need to use `age == 'overage'` instead of `>=`.

But there are some logical problems. You described that the input of Age and Name should be the same. It would be more sensefull (I guess) that the age entered schould be greater or equal than ten. Therefore your code using `>=` would be correct. But in this case you would need to compare two integers using the `>=` operator.
For this you need to change your strings to integers:
`name = int(input('Enter your name: ')` -> int() to convert string to integer
Additionally, change the string in your if-statement to be an integer, i.e. `if age >= 18`